# CMake command line for C++ #define

Tags: c++, command-line, cmake

I need to compile different versions of a certain project by adding compiler switches. Usually I would do this by using add_definitions or something like

```
set_property( TARGET mylib PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS _MYDEFINE=1 )
```

in the CMakeLists.txt file.

In this specific project however, **I am not allowed to modify any sources, including the CMakeLists.txt** file.

I was hoping that something like

```
cmake -D_MYDEFINE=1 <path to sources>
```

would generate a project file (Visual Studio 2008 in my case, but shouldn't matter) which includes _MYDEFINE=1 in its preprocessor definitions but in fact it won't.

What are my options here? Is there a different cmake command line option to achieve this? Feel free to suggest solutions not including the command line, as long as changing the project's CMakeLists.txt is not necessary.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-D_MYDEFINE=1" <path to sources>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I managed to do it this way now:

I was able to convince everybody to add the following lines to the common CMakeLists.txt:

```
IF (NOT DEFINED _MYDEFINE)
    SET(_MYDEFINE <default value>)
ENDIF()
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_MYDEFINE=${_MYDEFINE})
```

(No it is not really called "MYDEFINE", and <default value> is just a placeholder, I just replaced all that for this example)

This does not change the current behaviour of compiling with no additional compiler flags and is thus a valid change.

And it allows you to do

```
cmake -D_MYDEFINE=<my value> <path to sources>
```

where this cmake definition will be mapped to a C++ precompiler definition when cmake creates the project file.

Comment: ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_MYDEFINE)

Comment: Instead of conditional setting of `_MYDEFINE` variable it is better to set CACHE variable: `SET(_MYDEFINE CACHE STRING "Additional definition" <default value>)`. This reflects the meaning of the variable: **user-provided parameter**.

Answer (score 11):

**Container `CMakeLists.txt` solution**

Tricky solution:

Your read only `CMakeList.txt` path: `${path}/ReadOnlyProject/CMakeLists.txt`

Create a new `CMakeList.txt` to upper to the read only library (`${path}/CMakeLists.txt`):

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.0)
PROJECT (FAKE_PROJECT)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_MYDEFINE=1)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(ReadOnlyProject)
```

Now use your new project (`FAKE_PROJECT`) to compile. If the `ReadOnlyProject` does not set compilers definitions directly, it could work.

---

**On Visual Studio 2010:**

Try to modify `c:\Users\${username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` to add custom compiler settings.

You should add the followings:

```
<Project>
  ...
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>__MYDEFINE=1;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hm my %APPDATA%\Microsoft folder doesn't have any MSBuild folder (I'm on Windows XP btw)

Comment: Ok, I am using Visual Studio 2010. I will look for 2008 settings.

Comment: +1 for Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props update, needed to add prepocessor directive without changing .vcxproj

Comment: The Container CMakeLists.txt solution seems not working with projects using CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.

Answer (score 10):

To pass a C++ or C pre-processor define without modifying any CMake source files, use the environment variables `CFLAGS` for C or `CXXFLAGS` for C++ respectively, e.g.:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS="-D_MY_DEFINE=1 -D_MY_OTHER_DEFINE=1"
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

Also see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html).