# How to modify or redefine the Macro value from command line using CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

I want to change the macro value from the command line using `CMakeList.txt`. I have

```
#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER  1
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef NAME
#define NAME "MyName"  //string format
#endif
```

I found some links -> [How to define a C++ preprocessor macro through the command line with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564337/how-to-define-a-c-preprocessor-macro-through-the-command-line-with-cmake). There they say to add `add_definitions(-DNUMBER=5)` in CMake and it is working I can change the value using this way.

I want some way where I can change the value using command-Line. Like
`add_definitions(-DNUMBER=NUMBERX)`
and from command Line we provide the number `cmake NUMBERX=100. and NAMEX="ALEXA".`
Or some other way instead `add_definitions()`.

Comment: It may work if you spelt add_defin**i**tions correctly.  There is no a in definitions

Comment: Even the question you refer to has [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10364240/3440745) with option-approach, which allows to set specific macro definition conditionally, depending from the command line parameter. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533742/3440745) to the duplicate question describes using a command-line value directly as a macro value.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a cache variable for the user to provide this option at the time of configuring the project. For modifying an existing project I recommend using `cmake-gui`; cache variables will show up there for you to modify.

```
set(MY_PROJECT_DEFINITION_NAME "default-value" CACHE STRING "compiler definition for the NAME macro") # you could choose another name for the variable, of course

#I recommend adding the definition on a per-target basis, but it could be used with add_definitions too
target_compile_definitions(my_project PRIVATE "NAME=${MY_PROJECT_DEFINITION_NAME}") # another visibility may be appropriate
```

Configure your project using

```
cmake -D "MY_PROJECT_DEFINITION_NAME=non-default-value" -S source_dir_path -B build_dir_path
```

Leaving you `-D "MY_PROJECT_DEFINITION_NAME=non-default-value"` will result in `MY_PROJECT_DEFINITION_NAME` taking the value of `default-value`.

You may want to take a look at the exact syntax/type options in the [documentation of the `set` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) btw.